# Missing "app engine service account" in developers console

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently in the proces of updating an old appengine application to use the new cloudstorage based files API (python).

This also means setting up cloudstorage for this application.

I've done this successfully but my application isn't able to actually upload to the cloudstorage bucket. After some IRC debugging it turns out this is probably related to this account not having an "App Engine Service Account in it's permissions section.

Explicitly adding @appspot.gserviceaccount.com to the buckets permissions (user permission owner role) solves the problem. But still the application permission configuration is in some inconsistent state since it's missing this account.

Is there a way to reset/update these permissions/users?

(Creating a fresh / new application and moving to it is not really an option at this point)

[image: current permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out google provides [direct support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/files_api_deprecation) for the files API migration. The solution is to just manually add the user back (i.e. @appspot.gserviceaccount.com) to your project. The user was never removed internally.

Comment: Can you please accept your own answer so the question is properly seen as solved? Thanks!